# RuntimeError and TypeError when trying to call wm.event_timer_add

Tags: python, scripting

I'm currently working on a script for blender and I used the Modal Timer Template.
The problem is that one line is constantly giving me errors.

Here the source code:

```
def execute(self, context):
    wm = context.window_manager
    self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
    wm.modal_handler_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

And I get the output message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/tobias/Datenablage/Programmieren/python/Artnet_Visualizer/Blender_implementation.blend/sniffer_timed.py", line 62, in <module>
    File "/home/tobias/Temp/blender-2.80-f36efe0e2ad-linux-glibc224-x86_64/2.80/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 200, in __call__
        ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/tobias/Datenablage/Programmieren/python/Artnet_Visualizer/Blender_implementation.blend/sniffer_timed.py", line 41, in execute
TypeError: WindowManager.event_timer_add(): required parameter "window" to be a keyword argument!
location: /home/tobias/Temp/blender-2.80-f36efe0e2ad-linux-glibc224-x86_64/2.80/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:200
```

I'm kinda new to scripting in Blender so I have no idea what I should do.

Thanks for your help

Comment: There are  many changes in 2.80 and it appears this could be one. Given the  error message try `wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)` ie  make it a keyword argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment above by [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/15543/batfinger) worked:

There are many changes in 2.80 and it appears this could be one. Given the error message try `wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)` ie make it a keyword argument.

Comment: Worth also mentioning. A keyword argument has a default,  (Haven't checked but) Most probable default in this case is `context.window`.  If this is the case can use `wm.event_timer_add(0.1)`